# Is dropping foreign key constriants an event in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, foreign-key, oracle-11g, ddl-trigger

I wrote the following trigger in Oracle:

```
create or replace trigger foreign_drop before ddl on database
begin
  insert into ddl_log
  select ora_sysevent, ora_dict_obj_owner, ora_dict_obj_name, null, user, 
sysdate
  from dual;
end foreign_drop;
```

It fires whenever a DDL event happens. But when I drop a foreign key constraint, nothing is recorded. Is dropping a foreign key constraints considered an event? How could I record the action of dropping a foreign key constraint?

Answer (score 2):

The following trigger captures the drop constraint operation.

```
create or replace trigger foreign_drop after create or alter or drop on database
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('DDL Fired!');
end foreign_drop;
/
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> CREATE TABLE t2
( id number,
  CONSTRAINT fk_id
    FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES t1(id)
);  2    3    4    5    6  
DDL Fired!

Table created.

SQL> alter table t2 drop constraint fk_id;
DDL Fired!

Table altered.
```

Answer (score 2):

> How could I record the action of dropping a foreign key constraint?

Instead of reinventing the wheel, use the built-in support for auditing.

Dropping a constraint is an `ALTER TABLE` statement.
So enable auditing and audit `ALTER TABLE` statement as:

```
audit alter table;
```